# Can`t insert Data to Local DataBase because of AttachDbFilename

Tags: c#, local-database

Today I'm making a Local Database that should later function on other computers. Because of that I coded this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Now I can't use the database which is in the normal folder `./repos/WindowsFormsApp` and not in `./bin/Debug`. How can I navigate out of the debug and bin folder to get to the windowsformsapp folder that I can access the database and use it on other PCs?

Comment: Never use both "Data Source" and "AttachDbFilename".  Data Source is when a mdf file is attached to a Server. AttachDbFilename is when the mdf file is not attached to the server (localDb).

Comment: Then how can I use my local database on other computers?

Comment: The connection string should not be sewn into the application code. It should be taken from an external config.

Comment: Local means not on other computers?  Normally when you have a local Db there is a copy of the mdf file on each computer where you use it.  You do not have one central database.  The server is so you can have a common database for many computers.  With local database you create an empty database and install the empty database on each computer.

Comment: Thats what I mean :)